# Multiple Calendars without new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make an app where Users can make appointments on specifically rooms (User has_many appointments and rooms has_many appointments)

I'm using event_calendar gem. It is a simple gem, but makes everything that I need, shows a calendar with my appointments.

But how can I have one calendar to one room ? Calendar, in this gem, is not a model, so there isn't a relation of has_one

Can I make something like this on routes.rb

```
  match 'room/:id/calendar(/:year(/:month))' => 'calendar#index', :as => :calendar, :constraints => {:year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/}, via: [:get]
```

and on my calendar index filter by that room id ? something like this:

```
def index
  @month = (params[:month] || (Time.zone || Time).now.month).to_i
  @year = (params[:year] || (Time.zone || Time).now.year).to_i

  @shown_month = Date.civil(@year, @month)
  @event_strips = Appointment.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month)
  #Here is where I would filter by room id
  @filtered = @event_strips.find(params[:id])
end
```

I'm on Ruby 2 and Rails 4. Thanks in advance

Comment: So - what happened when you tried the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a find option to

```
Appointment.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month)
```

like

```
Appointment.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month,0, {})
```

where the last hash is what you'd pass into scoped()

eg.

```
Appointment.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month,0, {:conditions => "id == 1"})
```

This hasn't been tested but it's what you'd do.

you can see how it gets used by looking at
https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar/blob/master/lib/event_calendar.rb

specifically at the events_for_date_range method.

Comment: no worries - when in doubt, look at the source :) It's surprisingly easy and only gets easier with practice.